# NSCoding : How to create required init in inherited classes

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

I have the same question as vince ([NSCoding required initializer in inherited classes in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445556/nscoding-required-initializer-in-inherited-classes-in-swift))

I've a class 'Source' and a subclass 'RSSSource'. Theses classes conforms to `NSObject` and `NSCoding` which I want to be able to persist with `NSKeyedArchiver`.

I don't know how to create the required convenience `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` in the subclass. I would like to call the convenience `init` of the superclass.

PS: I know that I should post a comment on his thread but I can't. (reputation too low)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
class Source: NSObject, NSCoding {

  var name: String?

  func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as? String
  }

}

class RSSSource: Source {

  var rssName: String?

  override func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "rssName")
    super.encodeWithCoder(aCoder)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    rssName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("rssName") as? String
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have try the it, it just auto add the coding. You don't need to add the your coding by yourself otherwise you want to change.

sample coding:

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)

{

fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

}
```